# Solve an equation which contains binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have the following equation: 
$${{x}\choose{3}}=10$$
I want to solve it for $x$ so I wrote: 
$${{x}\choose{3}}=\frac{x!}{3!(x-3)!}=10$$
which follows: 
$$\frac{x!}{(x-3)!}=60$$
I wonder how to proceed from here and solve for $x$? As $(x-3)!\neq x!-3!$.

Comment: Think how to further simplify the left-hand side with the division. Plug in the definition of the factorial.

Comment: Would you accept $-1 \pm\sqrt{-11}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Simplifying $$\binom{x}{3}=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{1\cdot 2\cdot3}$$ we get $$\frac{x^3-3x^2+2x}{6}=10$$

Answer (score 4):

$$x!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot(...)\cdot(x-3)\cdot(x-2)\cdot(x-1)\cdot x$$
$$3!(x-3)!=6\cdot1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot(...)\cdot(x-3)$$
Hence
$$\frac{x!}{3!(x-3)!}=\frac{x(x-2)(x-1)}{6}=10$$
and solve from there.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x!}{(x-3)!} = x(x-1)(x-2)$$
as $x(x-1)(x-2)=60$ which is a cubic equation it can easily be solved
giving $x=5$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $$\binom{x}{3} = \frac{(x)(x-1)(x-2)}{6}$$

$$ \frac{(x)(x-1)(x-2)}{6} = 10 \implies (x)(x-1)(x-2)-60 = 0$$
$$ x^3 -3x^2+2x-60 = 0$$

You can factorise the above cubic equation to finish off